# ICU: ucnv_convertEx – detect encoding error on the fly

Tags: c++, c, unicode, character-encoding, icu

Is it possible to detect encoding errors with ICU at conversion time, or is it necessary to pre or post check the conversion?

Given the initialization where a conversion from UTF8 to UTF32 is setup:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "unicode/ucnv.h"     /* C Converter API */

static void eval(UConverter* from, UConverter* to);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    UConverter*  from;
    UConverter*  to;
    UErrorCode   status;

    /* Initialize converter from UTF8 to Unicode ___________________________*/
    status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
    from   = ucnv_open("UTF-8", &status);
    if( ! from || ! U_SUCCESS(status) ) return 1; 
    status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
    to     = ucnv_open("UTF32", &status);
    if( ! to || ! U_SUCCESS(status) ) return 1; 
    /*______________________________________________________________________*/

    eval(from, to);
    return 0;
}
```

Then, applying the conversion using `ucnv_convertEx` via

```c
static void eval(UConverter* from, UConverter* to) 
{
    UErrorCode  status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
    uint32_t    drain[1024];
    uint32_t*   drain_p = &drain[0];
    uint32_t*   p       = &drain[0];

    /* UTF8 sequence with error in third byte ______________________________*/
    const char  source[] = { "\xED\x8A\x0A\x0A" }; 
    const char* source_p = &source[0];

    ucnv_convertEx(to, from, (char**)&drain_p, (char*)&drain[1024],
                   &source_p, &source[5],
                   NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, /* reset = */TRUE, /* flush = */TRUE,
                   &status);

    /* Print conversion result _____________________________________________*/
    printf("source_p: source + %i;\n", (int)(source_p - &source[0]));
    printf("status:   %s;\n", u_errorName(status));
    printf("drain:    (n=%i)[", (int)(drain_p - &drain[0]));
    for(p=&drain[0]; p != drain_p ; ++p) { printf("%06X ", (int)*p); }
    printf("]\n");
}
```

where `source` contains an inadmissible UTF8 code unit sequence, the function should somehow report an error. Storing the above fragments in "test.c" and compiling the above code with

```
$ gcc test.c $(icu-config --ldflags) -o test
```

The output of `./test` is (surprisingly):

```
source_p: source + 5;
status:   U_ZERO_ERROR;
drain:    (n=5)[00FEFF 00FFFD 00000A 00000A 000000 ]
```

So, no obvious sign of a detected error. Can error detection be done more elegantly than manually checking the content?

Comment: You could set up an error callback.  q.v. http://userguide.icu-project.org/conversion/converters#TOC-Error-Callbacks

Comment: @Eljay, would you mind adorning the above code fragment to apply the callback for error detection? In the documentation, it is not clear to me what 'oldAction' would be.

Comment: If you have `C++11` you can use the Standard Library to do this conversion, which **does** signal encoding errors.

Comment: (In all fairness, regarding your example, UTF8 encoding errors can trivially be checked and it does not require an external library at all. But I suppose you are looking for a more generalized solution.)

Comment: The potential for failed communication of text metadata (character encoding), data corruption during storage or transport and prior mojibake errors are quite independent of your need to convert from one encoding to another.

Comment: @Tom Blodget: In the context of lexical analysis, it absolutely makes sense to consider an encoding error as a lexical error. It is also performance-wise advantageous to do both, lexical analysis and encoding check, in a single run (as currently implemented in Quex http://quex.sourceforge.net [shameless plug]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Eljay suggests in the comments, you can use an error callback. You don't even need to write your own, since the built-in `UCNV_TO_U_CALLBACK_STOP` will do what you want (ie, return a failure for any bad characters).

```
int TestIt()
{
  UConverter* utf8conv{};
  UConverter* utf32conv{};
  UErrorCode status{ U_ZERO_ERROR };

  utf8conv = ucnv_open("UTF8", &status);

  if (!U_SUCCESS(status))
  {
    return 1;
  }

  utf32conv = ucnv_open("UTF32", &status);

  if (!U_SUCCESS(status))
  {
    return 2;
  }

  const char source[] =  { "\xED\x8A\x0A\x0A" };
  uint32_t target[10]{ 0 };

  ucnv_setToUCallBack(utf8conv, UCNV_TO_U_CALLBACK_STOP, nullptr, 
    nullptr, nullptr, &status);

  if (!U_SUCCESS(status))
  {
    return 3;
  }

  auto sourcePtr = source;
  auto sourceEnd = source + ARRAYSIZE(source);
  auto targetPtr = target;
  auto targetEnd = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(target + ARRAYSIZE(target));

  ucnv_convertEx(utf32conv, utf8conv, reinterpret_cast<char**>(&targetPtr),
    targetEnd, &sourcePtr, sourceEnd, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, 
    TRUE, TRUE, &status);

  if (!U_SUCCESS(status))
  {
    return 4;
  }

  printf("Converted '%s' to '", source);
  for (auto start = target; start != targetPtr; start++)
  {
    printf("\\x%x", *start);
  }
  printf("'\r\n");

  return 0;
}
```

This should return `4` for invalid Unicode codepoints, and print out the UTF-32 values if it was successful. It's unlikely we'd get an error from `ucnv_setToUCallBack`, but we check just in case. In the example above, we pass `nullptr` for the previous action since we don't care what it was and don't need to reset it.